# Using AWS Mobile Services for an IOS App

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I paying someone to develop an IOS app for me (similar to instagram but with IM functions). Will the app be developed on a apple developers account then linked to the AWS mobile services or developed using AWS mobile services? What is the advantages or disadvantages of both methods?

Comment: These two methods are not comparable. You need Apple developer account to develop apps for Apple platforms. It is good approach by your vendor to use AWS mobile services for application backend.

Comment: Ok I understand, so to confirm...IOS app will need to be developed using the apple developer account and then linked to the AWS mobile services endpoints....AWS mobile services indicate that apps can be developed by downloading the mobile SDK, that is why I was confused.

Comment: Correct. AWS Mobile Services is a set of SDKs and backend services that can be used to support development and production of your mobile app.